# After registering Airplay receiver on iOS, it won't connect

Tags: ios, connection, airplay, mirroring

After successfully registering an Airplay service on iOS, I can see it in the list of Airplay receiver in the Control Center. When clicking on it, it tries to connect but ends in an error alert (Connection to "myDevice" not possible).

I'm using the DNSServiceRegister command from the dns-sd library and I'm also sending a TXTRecord.

```
TXTRecordRef txtRecord;
TXTRecordCreate(&txtRecord, 0, NULL);
TXTRecordSetValue(&txtRecord, "deviceid", strlen("E4:83:E5:BE:2C:E6"), "E4:83:E5:BE:2C:E6");
TXTRecordSetValue(&txtRecord, "features", strlen("0x5A7FFFF7,0x1E"), "0x5A7FFFF7,0x1E");
TXTRecordSetValue(&txtRecord, "flags", strlen("0x4"), "0x4");
TXTRecordSetValue(&txtRecord, "model", strlen("AppleTV3,2"), "AppleTV3,2");
TXTRecordSetValue(&txtRecord, "pk", strlen("ef9b9591269732952ae02e43d9a856fd58a5bd53f845978a8e08363897abb955"),"ef9b9591269732952ae02e43d9a856fd58a5bd53f845978a8e08363897abb955");
TXTRecordSetValue(&txtRecord, "pi", strlen("5e66cf9b-0a39-4e0c-9d32-081a8ce63231"),"5e66cf9b-0a39-4e0c-9d32-081a8ce63231");
TXTRecordSetValue(&txtRecord, "srcvers", strlen("220.68"), "220.68");
TXTRecordSetValue(&txtRecord, "vv", strlen("2"), "2");

...

DNSServiceRegister(&dnssd_service, 0, 0, [serviceString UTF8String], "_airplay._tcp", "local.", "myname.local", port, TXTRecordGetLength(&txtRecord), TXTRecordGetBytesPtr(&txtRecord), NULL, NULL);
```

Any ideas why this works only as far as adding the service to the list, but iOS devices cannot connect to it?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with adding some commands after

```
DNSServiceRegister(...);
```

I added:

```
/* Converts ascii text to in_addr struct.  NULL is returned if the
 address can not be found. */
struct in_addr *atoaddr(char *address) {
    struct hostent *host;
    static struct in_addr saddr;

    /* First try it as aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd. */
    saddr.s_addr = inet_addr(address);
    if (saddr.s_addr != -1) {
        return &saddr;
    }
    host = gethostbyname(address);
    if (host != NULL) {
        return (struct in_addr *) *host->h_addr_list;
    }
    return NULL;
}
void mycallback(DNSServiceRef sdRef, DNSRecordRef RecordRef, DNSServiceFlags flags, DNSServiceErrorType errorCode, void *context) {
    printf("Callback hit\n");
}

...

DNSRecordRef recordRef = malloc(sizeof(DNSRecordRef));
DNSServiceRef mainRef;
DNSServiceErrorType error = DNSServiceCreateConnection(&mainRef);
if (error) {
    printf("DNSServiceCreateConnection failed\n");
    exit(1);
}

DNSServiceRef registerServiceRef = mainRef;
DNSServiceErrorType errE = DNSServiceRegisterRecord( registerServiceRef, &recordRef, kDNSServiceFlagsShared, 0, "myname.local", kDNSServiceType_A, kDNSServiceClass_IN, sizeof(addr), addr, 0, mycallback, NULL);
```

Maybe this helps somebody.